# How do i make my discord.py bot pick an random line in a .txt file and reply to a message

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

Ok so i am making a gen bot for me and my friends and i wanted to know how do i make my bot reply to the message with a account from a .txt file that i put in the folder with the bot please help me thank you

i tried `

```
import random

@client.command()
async def color(ctx):
    responses = ['red',
                 'blue',
                 'green',
                 'purple',
                 'Add more',]
    await ctx.send(f'Color: {random.choice(responses)}')
```

` but i didnt want to put it all in one line in the responses

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read a file line-by-line into a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277503/how-to-read-a-file-line-by-line-into-a-list)

Answer (score 0):

You could add something like this to your code:

```
import random


def readTxtLines(filename):
    with open(filename, "r") as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
    return lines


def getRandomLine(lines):
    return random.choice(lines).strip()


print(getRandomLine(readTxtLines("test.txt")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method in cog form:

```py
import random

@commands.command()
async def color(self,ctx):
    filename1=open('cogs/color.txt','r')
    wordList1=[line.rstrip('\n') for line in filename1]
    filename1.close()
    out1 = random.choice(wordList1)
    await ctx.send(f"color: {out1}")
```